# examples for controling gradle via java api?

Tags: java, scala, gradle

I'm looking to integrate Multi-OS engine with my scala libgdx app.
Currently, I have scala-libgdx set up (from https://github.com/charafau/scala-libgdx.g8), but it's missing the iOS part due to discontinuation of robovm.
Of course, there's sbt-moe(https://github.com/HevyLight/sbt-moe), but the author has not yet answered my email for help understanding its usage.

Anyway, back to the point: is there a way to 'control' gradle via some java interface? If so, are there any examples running around?

ps: I'm thinking about controlling gradle from sbt

Comment: Use [gradle Api](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/)

Comment: @LazerBanana well I edited this question to include examples...

Comment: in this case, this is more a question seeking a software recommendation and this website is not ideal for that kind a question. try here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and delete this question, please.